# Increment and forward an integer using pipes in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am trying to write a program that initializes an integer in the parent and then in the first fork() we take that value increment it and pass it along the tube to the next process called by the current child. This goes on for 2 more times. My problem is that I initiate the integer to 96 and ideally since we have 3 processes the program should return 99. But instead, it returns 'a', which means it has only incremented once.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int status;
        int i;

        int pipes[4];

        pipe(pipes);
        pipe(pipes + 2);
        int num = 96;

        if (fork() == 0)
        {
                dup2(pipes[1], 1);

                close(pipes[0]);
                close(pipes[1]);
                close(pipes[2]);
                close(pipes[3]);
                num++;
                write(pipes[1], &num, sizeof(int));
        }
        else
        {
                if (fork() == 0)
                {
                        dup2(pipes[0], 0);
                        dup2(pipes[3], 1);

                        close(pipes[0]);
                        close(pipes[1]);
                        close(pipes[2]);
                        close(pipes[3]);
                        read(pipes[0], &num, sizeof(int));
                        num++;
                        write(pipes[3], &num, sizeof(int));
                }
                else
                {
                        if (fork() == 0)
                        {
                                dup2(pipes[2], 0);
                                close(pipes[0]);
                                close(pipes[1]);
                                close(pipes[2]);
                                close(pipes[3]);
                                read(pipes[2], &num, sizeof(int));
                                num++;
                                write(1, &num, sizeof(int));
                        }
                }
        }

        close(pipes[0]);
        close(pipes[1]);
        close(pipes[2]);
        close(pipes[3]);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                wait(&status);
}
```

1. How do I make it so that an integer is printed?
2. Why does my increment work only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `close(pipe[0])` and then try to read from it.  Read from the dup'd fd instead.  You would notice this error if you checked the values returned from `read` and `write`.

To print an integer, use `printf("%d", num)` instead of write.  The reason `num` increments only once is that the `read` in the final child fails and does not change `num`, so after the `read` num retains the value it had when it was initialized.

All you need to do is either remove the `close` calls from inside the conditions (all of the pipes get closed twice in the current code (or, more accurately, they are closed once and then a second attempt to close them fails, but the failure goes unnoticed)) or read/write from/to the dup'd fd.